# Spring Data JPA: How to update entity when embedded collection is updated using a separate repository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

## Overview

I have a `Customer` entity with an embedded collection of `Order`s. `Customer`s and `Order`s are updated using  separate Spring Data JPA repositories (`CustomerRepository` & `OrderRepository`).

The following operations are performed within a transactional method:

1. An order is added for a customer using the `OrderRepository`'s `save` method
2. The customer is read using the `CustomerRepository`'s `findById` method

Expected result: The customer contains the order

Actual result: The customer does *NOT* contain the order

## Sample Project

- https://github.com/fmck3516/jpa-update-embedded-collection
- Hibernate 6.1.7.Final
- Spring Boot Version 3.0.4

## Details

Customer:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    List<Order> orders;

}
```

Order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    Customer customer;

}
```

I use Spring Data repositories for read/write operations:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, String> {
}
```

Updates to the embedded orders collection using the `OrderRepository` are not reflected on the customer entity:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.id = "customer-0";

customer = customerRepository.save(customer);

Order order = new Order();
order.id = "order-0";
order.customer = customer;

orderRepository.save(order);

System.out.println(customerRepository.findById("customer-0"));
```

Expected Output:

`Optional[Customer{id='customer-0', orders=[Order{id='order-0', customer=customer-0}]}]`

Actual Output:

`Optional[Customer{id='customer-0', orders=null}]`

I'm aware of the following solutions / workarounds:

- Replace `save` with `saveAndFlush` and use `EntityManager` to refresh the customer object: This will generate the expected output.
- Assign the order to the customer. Save the order and the customer.
- Re-read the customer in a new transaction.

Unfortunately, I'm dealing with an existing code base where database access is scattered. It is not trivial to implement any of those alternatives.

Is there a way to tell JPA to "auto-magically" update the `Customer` entity whenever the embedded `Order` collection is updated via the `OrderRepository`?

Comment: AFAIK not possible as its the same transaction and the order was not flushed to database yet, thus making it impossible for the customer to find it.

Comment: Yes, it is called `saveAndFlush` spring cant do magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify which JPA implementation you are using and there is no JPA standard way to do this.
But Hibernate offers a way to keep the two sides of a bidirectional relationship in sync.
I never used it so I'll just quote this [article by Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-easiest-way-to-manage-bi-directional-associations/):

> You just need to add a Maven or Gradle plugin to your build process, which will add the required code the class files of your entities.
>
> The following configuration adds the hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin to your maven build and generates the required code to manage bidirectional associations.
>
> ```xml
> <project>
>     ...
>      
>     <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>                 <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <configuration>
>                             <failOnError>true</failOnError>
>                             <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
>                         </configuration>
>                         <goals>
>                             <goal>enhance</goal>
>                         </goals>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
> </project>
> ```
>
> That’s all you need to do. During your next Maven build, the plugin will add additional code into the setter methods of the to-one sides of your bi-directional associations. This code updates the other end of the association so that you don’t need to do it yourself.

Comment: I've attached a link to a self-contained demo project: https://github.com/fmck3516/jpa-update-embedded-collection (Hibernate 6.1.7.Final).

The plugin sounds like a solution for my problem. However, I'm so far unable to "make it work": https://github.com/fmck3516/jpa-update-embedded-collection/tree/gradle-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no two persistent objects of an entity with the same primary key can coexist in a persistent context(residing in the 1st Level Cache). As 'customer' is made persistent by calling:

```
customer = customerRepository.save(customer);
```

and as tx is not yet committed or session is not flushed the following call will not hit the DB

```
customerRepository.findById("customer-0")
```

Moreover, no records have been flushed to DB till now, everything is in persistentcontext, so the query will get the entity from 1st level cache/persistence context

Even if you had retrieved the existing customer record from db  and again fired a separate query to retrieve the same customer, it would have returned you the existing object in the persistence context retrieved in earlier query.

the orm framework will first see if an entity with a particular id is already in the persistent context or not, if yes then it would just return the object/entity from the persistence context or 1st level cache.

However, if you were using class instrumentation as suggested by 'Jens Schauder' above, instrumented code  would have taken care of to populate the relationship/association link.

Hibernate instrumentation was not available few years ago and we used to set the relationship explicitly, even these days I prefer doing the following (don't use both instrumentation and explicit setting of the relationship):

first, I would suggest initializing the list i.e. `List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>()`   and add a 'getter' for orders in your Customer class and do the following;

```
customer.getOrders().add(order);

order.setCustomer(customer);
```

if you do the above or use hibernate instrumentation your query will give you the expected result.

P.S. After making the above change to your project I am getting the following output:

Optional[Customer{id='customer-0', orders=[Order{id='order-0', customer=customer-0}]}]
Optional[Customer{id='customer-0', orders=[Order{id='order-0', customer=customer-0}]}]